# Inheritance in createjs 8 subclass instance produces error

Tags: javascript, subclass, createjs

I'm trying to use the new inheritance model in createjs version 8. I want to have  Tile inherit from createjs.Shape 
Here is the bare essential code.

```
//This is the Tile constructor
function Tile() { 
 this.Shape_constructor;
} 
var p = createjs.extend(Tile, createjs.Shape); //Tile is a subclass of shape
window.Tile = createjs.promote(Tile, "Shape");//  It needs this, but I do 
not completely understand this completely 

 var tile = new Tile();
 // tile should be an instance of createjs.Shape
 tile.graphics.beginFill('blue').drawRoundRect(0, 0, 150, 150, 15);   
 // produces Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'beginFill' of 
   undefinedUncaught  

 I created myshape = new createjs.Shape and the pgm works OK using myshape 
   instead of tile. 
The following shows that tile and myshape seem to have the same structure
 but they are clearly different in behavior.
console.log(tile instanceof Tile); // true
console.log(Tile instanceof createjs.Shape);//  false
console.log(tile instanceof createjs.Shape); // true
console.log(myshape instanceof createjs.Shape); // true

console.log(typeof tile == typeof Tile); // false
console.log(typeof Tile == typeof createjs.Shape); // true
console.log(typeof tile == typeof createjs.Shape); //  false
console.log(typeof myshape == typeof createjs.Shape); // false


I'm clearly missing something but what?
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the shape constructor properly:

```
this.Shape_constructor; // Wrong
this.Shape_constructor(); // Right
```

Not sure what you are trying to show with all your `instanceof` and `typeof` logs. The `Tile` class will not be an instance of `Shape`, for example, because the `Tile` class is not an instance.

Hope that helps.